# SSIS Package Execution Failed (Data Factory) - Script Component not loading code

Tags: azure, ssis, factory, azure-data-factory

Since last week, my SSIS packages running in Azure Data Factory (v2) are failing one by one. They haven't changed though. All the packages are failing with the same series of errors, as shown below.

The packages are running perfectly in Visual Studio, but when I deploy them to Data Factory, I got these messages.

Any thoughts on where to look?

I've tried to recompiled the script components, to redeploy the whole project. I've also tried to copy the C# code into a new component, unfortunately results in the same issue.

[image: Errors]

Comment: So the packages were running fine in ADF up until last week, and then you started seeing the errors?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. After that, I've tested them offline, and they all worked perfectly. Re-deploy didn't help.

Comment: What are the path/filename length errors referring to? Maybe there was a change on the ADF end that reduced the character limit for paths, causing the path to your script to become invalid?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Even tried deploying older code from source control that is currently working, when I redeploy to a new folder in ADF/SSISDB it returns the same `Script Task: Error: Cannot load script for execution.` Makes me believe that some recent update in ADF is the culprit, not our code.

Answer (score 0):

So I was driven kind of crazy by this, had the exact same problem, and was troubleshooting with the assistance of [Innovative Architects](https://www.innovativearchitects.com/), a group near Atlanta. And we discovered that ***LITERALLY TODAY*** Microsoft released an updated version that fixes this exact problem. So apparently it was a bug that they fixed.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/changelog-for-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-visual-studio-2017-1582) for the fix.